# asociativa por conjuntos MRU en c++ en la cache

Tags: c++

disculpen una pregunta alguien sabe como seria un ejemplo o el algoritmo de mru asociativa por conjuntos ya que he buscado ejemplo o algo mas o menos que se le parezca y no he llegado a nada

Comment: Desde revisión: Añade lo que hayas intentado, se tiene que ver tu esfuerzo por solucionar el problema; sugiero que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: ya he hecho la parte de la mru pero lo hice el codigo por correspondencia directa ya que ns como implementarle la parte de asocitiva por conjuntos debido a que no entiendo como podria hacerce de esa forma